# Type mismatch, when trying to get a variable in the sendkeyin command

Tags: vba, microstrategy

I am using VBA in microstation to come up with a simple find & replace program. I keep getting a type mismatch where my & Text_Find  and & Text Replace is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Main()


Dim Find_text() As String
Dim Replace_text() As String

Find_text = Split("20.50 35.43", " ")
Replace_text = Split("12.5 43.55", " ")

'   Start a command

    CadInputQueue.SendKeyin "MDL KEYIN FINDREPLACETEXT,CHNGTXT CHANGE DIALOGTEXT"

For i = 0 To UBound(Find_text)
    For j = 0 To UBound(Replace_text)

    MsgBox Find_text
    MsgBox Replace_text

    CadInputQueue.SendKeyin "FIND DIALOG SEARCHSTRING" & Find_text

    CadInputQueue.SendKeyin "FIND DIALOG REPLACESTRING" & Replace_text

    CadInputQueue.SendKeyin "CHANGE TEXT ALLFILTERED"


    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find_text and Replace_text are both arrays 
You will have to specify the element of the array to use 
Probably  `Find_text(i)  Replace_text(j)`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! Another problem i am facing now though... is that i have about 600 values to go in to my split.. this could be really stupid but i tried copying and pasting them in to the quotation marks but im assuming there is a limit. Any way around that? I do have the values in Column A and B of excel.. should i make it read from excel maybe?

Comment: Try `Find_text=Range("A1:A600")`